# How to change the value of a global variable within a local scope?

Tags: javascript

I need to change the value of the global variable within the scope of the function.

```js
const func = () => {
  let a = 'a';

  const alter = () => {
    a = 'c';
  }

  const ver = () => {
    console.log(a)
  }

  alter()
  ver()
}
func();
```

Comment: That's precisely what your code already does. (Except that `a` is not a global variable, it's just in the outer scope)

Comment: i dont see any global variables

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps or if not, why? Your question is confusing as you don't have any global variables declared. So if the answer is unhelpful maybe you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you might be struggling with how scopes work in JavaScript.

First, there is no global variable declared in your example. When `alter` is called, it looks for `a` which doesn't exist within its scope. So it looks to the outerscope which is `func`. `func` has `a` declared so this is where the **scope chain** ends, and the `a` that gets modified is the one inside `func`.

If you wanted `a` to be "global" you'd have to lift the declaration outside the scope of any function. This would cause your example to modify the `a` in global scope.

However if you leave your example as-is and declare another `a` in the global scope (i.e. you have two declarations for `a`), then your example would modify the value of `a` within `func` but not the global `a`.

If you want to modify a global variable when you have another variable with the same name in the middle of the scope chain you can do this:

```js
let a = 'b'; // this is our global `a` declaration

const func = () => {
  let a = 'a'; // here we declare a new `a` inside the scope of `func`

  const alter = () => {
    window.a = 'c'; // modifies the global `a`
  }

  const ver = () => {
    console.log(window.a); // this will log `c`

    /* 
     * This log below will output `a` as it is referencing the first `a`
     * declared along the scope chain, which is in `func` (the outer scope)
     * and it hasn't been modified.
     */
    console.log(a);
  }

  alter();
  ver();
}
func();
```